# Не устанавливается django_compressor в Windows

Tags: python, django, pip

При установке компрессор в django возникают проблемы. Кто может объяснить суть и как решить?

```
Collecting django_compressor
  Using cached django_compressor-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rjsmin==1.0.12 (from django_compressor)
  Using cached rjsmin-1.0.12.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: django-appconf>=1.0 in c:\python\django projects\barakatex\lib\site-packages (from django_compressor)
Collecting rcssmin==1.0.6 (from django_compressor)
  Using cached rcssmin-1.0.6.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: rjsmin, rcssmin, django-compressor
  Running setup.py install for rjsmin: started
    Running setup.py install for rjsmin: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command "c:\python\django projects\barakatex\scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-x_9thics\\rjsmin\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vc4k97qp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "c:\python\django projects\barakatex\include\site\python3.5\rjsmin":
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    copying .\rjsmin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    running build_ext
    building '_rjsmin' extension
    error: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: **Не удается найти указанный файл** что здесь не понятно?

Comment: @alexolut не удаётся найти **какой** файл и откуда его взять? (Впрочем, в ответе уже расписали)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компрессор зависим от пакетов rccsmin и rjsmin. Каждый из них при установке пытается собрать из исходников бинарник расширения. Сборка из исходников под управлением операционной системы Windows может получиться только на специально подготовленном для этого компьютере. Но эти зависимости можно установить и без компиляции расширений. Выполните последовательность команд:

```
pip install rcssmin --install-option="--without-c-extensions"
pip install rjsmin --install-option="--without-c-extensions"
pip install django-compressor
```

Comment: pip install rjsmin --install-option="--without-c-extensions"
выдаёт ошибку "error: option --without-c-extensions not recognized"

Comment: @Вячеслав 7 дней назад [нужда в этой опции исчезла](https://github.com/ndparker/rjsmin/commit/285a4cbb21c8cd196e3333259a31e5634ad78285).